# jquery move clicked list item to first visible item in list carousel

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

hey i have a carousel of list items, what i would like to be able to do is when the user clicks on a list item (say the 4th visible item on the list) the clicked item scrolls left and ends up in the first visible position.

oh, i'm using the jCarousel plug-in to make the carousel work.

i've got a link:

[link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2483833/shareCarousel/index.html)

not really sure how to even begin, any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my carousel, which may help (it has click events and animations):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #wrapper { width: 300px; overflow: hidden; height: 100px; min-height: 100px; position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0;  }
            #ul { width: 9999px; height: 100px; position: absolute; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; text-align: center;  }
            .li { float: left; list-style-type: none; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;  }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                for (var i = 24; i > 0; i--) {
                    $('#ul').append('<li class="li" style="z-index: '+i+'"><img src="http://www.jamesgraygallery.com/artimages/Mee%20Kyung%20Shim/slides/Last%20Summer,50x50.jpg" alt="'+i+'" width="100" height="100"</li>');
                }

                $('#ul').css({ //Reset the carousel to the center
                    'left': -($('.li').size()*$('.li').width())/2
                });

                var howMany = $('.li').size();
                var halfIt = howMany/2;
                var merp = $('.li').index('#ul');

                $('#right').click(function() {  //Right button
                    $('#ul').animate({
                        left: '-='+($('.li').width()*3) //Move the images
                    }, 500);
                    return false;
                });

                $('#left').click(function() {  //Left button
                    $('#ul').animate({
                        left: '+='+($('.li').width()*3) //Move the images
                    }, 500);
                    return false;
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <ul id="ul">

            </ul><br />
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="right">right</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" id="left">left</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This should be a good place to get you started. ^_^

**note:** This will not give you the CLICK-TO-ANIMATE function you require, but I can't do it all for you can I? :)